# Ajax function requests and concurrency

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, concurrency, closures

I have an application I am developing that is going to make use of a lot of various ajax requests using JQuery. I thought the best way to prevent me repeating code was to write one (or two depending on how the app develops) wrapper Ajax function, the various objects I create then call the same function to return the data required.

The problem I am anticipating is, if I have, for example, 5 ajax requests all calling the same function to return the data at the same time, is this going to get muddled on its output where all 5 requests return the same data?

I've read into closures within functions, I'm not sure I entirely understand how they work, but am I right in saying that each call to the ajax wrapper function will create a closure and therefore the returned data will not get muddled?

Comment: If you mean if a callback can get the response from another ajax call then no, it won't/can't happen. There is one exception though. If your browser enables pipelining and your webserver is a version of Apache or IIS released prior to around 2005 (I don't remember the exact date but I remember it not being a problem around that time) then it can happen. In general you can assume it will work.

Comment: Also note: all browsers disable pipelining by default. You can't even enable it on Google Chrome and on Firefox you need to use `about:config`

Comment: So multiple use of the same function at the same time using different parameters to return data will not collide. Sorry just want to clarify.

Comment: Yes, they won't collide. I'm assuming you're using jQuery ajax or something similar and not manually wrapping XMLHttpRequest. A new XMLHttpRequest object should be created for every request to prevent collision. All the popular libraries already does this so no worries. But if you're doing it yourself you need to keep that in mind

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the help, I've decided to use the wrapper function most of my initial get requests but will likely use "web workers" for all posting so the UI is not compromised when doing these requests.